# What is wrong with scope of variable in javascript in this code block?

Tags: javascript, scope, chain

```
<script>
var fun1 = function(){alert('original')};
function decoratefun (f){
    return function(){
        console.log(f.toString());
        console.log(fun1.toString());
        console.log('-------------');

        return decoratefun.apply(this,arguments); 
    };
}

var fun1 = decoratefun(fun1);

fun1(); // this works
fun1()(); // but this doesn't, it complains 'f' is undefined
</script>
```

Why does the chain call on `fun1()` give an error like `f` is not defined? I have passed `f` using arguments object, why the second call says `f` not defined? That is a bit weird for me, I think `f` is still in scope in the chain call on `fun1()`, so why does the interpreter complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have pass 'f' using arguments object, why the second call says 'f' not defined?

`arguments` refers to the arguments of the anonymous function you return from `decoratefun`:

```
return function(){

};
```

And as you can see, this doesn't define any arguments nor are you passing any arguments to it when you call the function (`fun1()`). So you end up calling `decoratefun.apply(this,arguments)` without any arguments, which is why `f` is `undefined`. You can verify this by adding a `console.log(arguments)`.

It would work if you passed a function to `fun1`, e.g.

```
fun1(fun1);
```

However, I believe you just want to pass `f` directly instead

```
return decoratefun.call(this, f);
```

Comment: Or, I suppose if he wanted to keep all arguments even if he adds more, he could add a "var tempArguments" just above the anonymous function, and use that. Good find! I couldn't figure this out.